# Observables - prevent onCompleted for array

Tags: javascript, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable, angular2-observables

Let's say I have an array like so:

```
const values = [1,2,3];
```

I create an observable from this array like so:

```
const obs = Rx.Observable.from(values);
```

I subscribe like so:

```
obs.subscribe(
    function onNext(result){
        console.log('item =>', result);
    },
    function onError(e){
        console.error(e.stack || e);
    },
    function onCompleted(){
        console.log('observable is completed');
    }
);
```

the problem I am having is that if I push new items to the array like so:

```
setTimeout(function(){   
   values.push(4);
   values.push(5); 
   values.push(6);
}, 3000 );
```

these items (4,5,6) do not show up in the subscribe() callbacks!

So my question is, how can we create an observable array, that can "remain open" so that if items are pushed onto the array in the future, that the observer callbacks will fire?

I created a gist for this:

https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/677ad0a3adf41c04a60829921ba4c4c4

and here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mcq40Lmg/

Comment: With your current setup the observable will not watch for array updates. The observable is created with the values that it had initially. What you do need though is a subject.

Comment: @AadiDroid thanks, can you add an answer with more detail? I am totally new to observables

Comment: @AlexanderMills I would suggest that you learn the basic theory of the observer pattern and rx first. Learning by example will be painful.

Comment: well I am familiar with the observer pattern. RxJS and reactive programming seems to be a little bit more on top of that. I don't see RxJS to be any simpler than learning streams, where streams were much more difficult to fully comprehend compared with callbacks or promises.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't see how learning by example could be harder than learning by reading the docs, I usually learn nothing that way.

Comment: If you are interested - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150192/improving-observable-persistent-queue-mini-library

Comment: @AlexanderMills I'm not on codereview, but wait, what... did you just monkey patch your own object from inside a subscribe call?

Comment: Okay, I'm totally going to help you get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Is it possible to use a round robin strategy in your queue? Can you distribute queue items?

Comment: @Asti I am going to update the code review question, I made a bunch of changes since I first posted the question.

Comment: Join here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131652/rx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the capability to push values through direct calls, you will need to use a `Subject<T>`.

```
const values = Rx.Observable.Subject();

setTimeout(function(){

   values.onNext(4);
   values.onNext(5); 
   values.onNext(6);

}, 3000 );
```

Using subjects for routine operations is not considered a good practice, and goes against the spirit of Rx. Subjects are, in essence, the mutable variables of Rx.

You can mostly get whatever functionality you want from the built-in operators, or create new ones which combine existing ones.

Comment: this works for me, not sure why this makes things mutable?